# Java array of queues printing out only last element within for loop in print method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, printing, queue

I spent several hours working on this and even had my professor look at this and it seems to be printing out just the last element in the for loop. It seems to allows me to add the data structure information and initialize the array queue but it only print out the last element. Here is the sufficient code to assist with the question.

```
static  int MAX;
static final int amount =  6;
static boolean [] openflag;
static queue [] Clinic; 
static String [] Doctor;
final static String HEADING = "The clinic moniter of Dylan Rychlik";

public static void Listpaitents( ) {
    Paitent[] array;
    int queuechoice;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Which doctor would you like to 
print?");
    String InputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Doctor, HEADING, 
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 

    queuechoice = Integer.parseInt(InputString);

    if (openflag[queuechoice -1 ] == false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, that doctor is not aviable");
    }
    else {
        //Paitent[] array = null; 
        int limit;
        limit = Clinic[queuechoice -1 ].getSize();
        array = Clinic[queuechoice  -1 ].toArray();

        System.out.println(array[0]);
        System.out.println(array[1].Print());
        System.out.println(array[2].Print());

        //int size = Clinic[queuechoice -1].getSize();
        //System.out.println(limit);
        int x; String out = " Members of the list are: \n";

        // boolean exit = false;
        for(x = 0; x < limit; x++) {
            out += array[x].Print() + "\n";
            //System.out.println(out);
            // System.out.println(Clinic[queuechoice].toString() + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println(limit);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,out);
    }
}
```

Here this is the array() method in the queue clas

```
 public Paitent[] toArray() {
     int x;
     Paitent[] Array = new Paitent[Length];
     queuenode Current = rear;

     for (x = 1; ((Current != null) && (x <= Length));x++) {
         Array[x-1] = new Paitent();
         Array[x-1].update(Current.info);
         Current = Current.next; 
         //  System.out.println( Array[x-1].Print());
     }
     //System.out.println( Array[x-1].Print());
     return Array;
 }
```

Any finally here this is the print method

```
public String Print() {
    String outputString;
    outputString = "Paitent: " + "-" + name + "\n" + " Telephone number 
    telephone + " ID " + ID;
    return outputString; 
}
```

Any help you can give is really appreciated. I really have spent hours analyzing the code to come up a solution. Its a bulky program.

Comment: the print method

Comment: Fixed the issue. Thanks guys!!